# Ansible list of dicts - accessing keys after a list filter

Tags: dictionary, ansible, jinja2

Taking this playbook YAML:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  vars:
    list_of_dicts:
      - { key1: "cccc", key2: "dddd" }
      - { key1: "aaaa", key2: "bbbb" }
  tasks:
    - name: debug list
      debug:
        msg: "{{ list_of_dicts|sort(attribute='key1')|first }}"
```

How can I access the `dict` keys as a result of the filter chain?  The filter produces a `dict` that looks like this:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": {
        "key1": "aaaa",
        "key2": "bbbb"
    }
}
```

I just want to access `key2` in the filter chain - I pictured something like `...|first.key2` but that infers `first` is an object which it isn't (and similarly fails for `first['key2']`)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*This is for sure a duplicate, but I can't find corresponding answer. I wish SO had a better search engine.*

You can group expressions in Jinja2, like follows:

```
(list_of_dicts|sort(attribute='key1')|first).key2
```